# HuggingFace BERT `inputs_embeds` giving unexpected result

Tags: python, tensorflow, nlp, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model

The [HuggingFace BERT TensorFlow implementation](https://huggingface.co/transformers/model_doc/bert.html#tfbertmodel) allows us to feed in a precomputed embedding in place of the embedding lookup that is native to BERT. This is done using the model's `call` method's optional parameter `inputs_embeds` (in place of `input_ids`). To test this out, I wanted to make sure that if I *did* feed in BERT's embedding lookup, I would get the same result as having fed in the `input_ids` themselves.

The result of BERT's embedding lookup can be obtained by setting the BERT configuration parameter `output_hidden_states` to `True` and extracting the first tensor from the last output of the `call` method. (The remaining 12 outputs correspond to each of the 12 hidden layers.)

Thus, I wrote the following code to test my hypothesis:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from transformers import BertConfig, BertTokenizer, TFBertModel

bert_tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')

input_ids = tf.constant(bert_tokenizer.encode("Hello, my dog is cute", add_special_tokens=True))[None, :]
attention_mask = tf.stack([tf.ones(shape=(len(sent),)) for sent in input_ids])
token_type_ids = tf.stack([tf.ones(shape=(len(sent),)) for sent in input_ids])

config = BertConfig.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased', output_hidden_states=True)
bert_model = TFBertModel.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased', config=config)

result = bert_model(inputs={'input_ids': input_ids, 
                            'attention_mask': attention_mask, 
                             'token_type_ids': token_type_ids})
inputs_embeds = result[-1][0]
result2 = bert_model(inputs={'inputs_embeds': inputs_embeds, 
                            'attention_mask': attention_mask, 
                             'token_type_ids': token_type_ids})

print(tf.reduce_sum(tf.abs(result[0] - result2[0])))  # 458.2522, should be 0
```

Again, the output of the `call` method is a tuple. The first element of this tuple is the output of the last layer of BERT. Thus, I expected `result[0]` and `result2[0]` to match. **Why is this not the case?**

I am using Python 3.6.10 with `tensorflow` version 2.1.0 and `transformers` version 2.5.1.

**EDIT**: Looking at some of the [HuggingFace code](https://huggingface.co/transformers/_modules/transformers/modeling_bert.html), it seems that the raw embeddings that are looked up when `input_ids` is given or assigned when `inputs_embeds` is given are added to the positional embeddings and token type embeddings before being fed into subsequent layers. If this is the case, then it *may* be possible that what I'm getting from `result[-1][0]` is the raw embedding plus the positional and token type embeddings. This would mean that they are erroneously getting added in again when I feed `result[-1][0]` as `inputs_embeds` in order to calculate `result2`.

**Could someone please tell me if this is the case and if so, please explain how to get the positional and token type embeddings, so I can subtract them out?** Below is what I came up with for positional embeddings based on the equations given [here](https://medium.com/dissecting-bert/dissecting-bert-part-1-d3c3d495cdb3) (but according to the [BERT paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1810.04805.pdf), the positional embeddings may actually be learned, so I'm not sure if these are valid):

```
import numpy as np

positional_embeddings = np.stack([np.zeros(shape=(len(sent),768)) for sent in input_ids])
for s in range(len(positional_embeddings)):
    for i in range(len(positional_embeddings[s])):
        for j in range(len(positional_embeddings[s][i])):
            if j % 2 == 0:
                positional_embeddings[s][i][j] = np.sin(i/np.power(10000., j/768.))
            else:
                positional_embeddings[s][i][j] = np.cos(i/np.power(10000., (j-1.)/768.))
positional_embeddings = tf.constant(positional_embeddings)
inputs_embeds += positional_embeddings
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My intuition about positional and token type embeddings being added in turned out to be correct. After looking closely at the [code](https://huggingface.co/transformers/_modules/transformers/modeling_tf_bert.html), I replaced the line:

```
inputs_embeds = result[-1][0]
```

with the lines:

```
embeddings = bert_model.bert.get_input_embeddings().word_embeddings
inputs_embeds = tf.gather(embeddings, input_ids)
```

Now, the difference is 0.0, as expected.